# git-diff с именем файла и строкой в префиксе

Tags: git, diff

Хочу найти в дифе между двумя ветками все вхождения строки
`TODO` вместе с именем файла и номером строки.  Сейчас
использую:

```sh
$ git diff other-branch | grep TODO
```

Но вывод идёт без имени файла и строки.  То есть я получаю:

```
+// TODO A
+// TODO B
+// TODO C
```

А хочу что-то типа:

```
src/a.c:12+// TODO A
src/b.c:34+// TODO B
src/c.c:56+// TODO C
```

Comment: номера строки обязательны?

Comment: Крайне желательны, но если по-другому никак, можно и без.

Comment: чтобы присутствовали имена файлов и номера строк, добавьте их в шаблон для программы grep. а чтобы попадали только изменённые строки, ограничьте контекст опцией `-U0`. что-то вроде: `$ git diff -U0 другие аргументы и опции | grep 'искомая строка\|^+++\|^@'`